# YouTube api v3 channel/list return partial list

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to get all the channels in youtube.
When I use the channel list api, I have to put categoryId, I tried one of them and I saw that the amount of channels I get is very low ( e.g. I got around 1502)

When I use the regular search api and filter by type:channel I get tons of results...

Is there anything special about the channel list api which return only sunset and not full list ?

- this is not pagignation issue

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be working as intended to me. From the Channels.list() [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list), the required filters you can include (of which you can use only one), are:

> - categoryId
> - forUsername
> - id
> - managedByMe
> - mine
> - mySubscribers

where `categoryId` specifies a YouTube guide category, thereby requesting YouTube channels **associated with** that category. This won't give you a list of all channels, that's what you should be using `Search.list()` for (as you mentioned you had also tried).